# Why multiple apks created wth Adobe air 14 in flash professional having issues?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, google-play, multiple-apk

I am having multiple apks created wth Adobe air 14 in flash professional having issues when submitting to play store.

My research from 
http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html
here says, version code needs to be modified but in air-android manifest version code is not shown, if I add it forcefully where shall I put that tag?

Anyone who has faced same issues before?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the manifest version code in your app descriptor file. It's one of the manifest's attributes that AIR doesn't let you modify. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html

You should try supporting different screen sizes within the same APK. You can refer to this article for more info http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have different apks as my app has some addition features for large screens(i.e. tablets) though I found a work around for this and successfully submitted my apks on play store. I didn't changed the version code.
I played with the versionNumber and got it submitted.
But